# Не получается вывести в консоль список файлов

Tags: linux, файлы, bash

У меня есть файл, в котором записаны строки через перенос (`\n\r`). Я делаю:

```
> $(< data.csv)
```

Но получаю на первой же строке:

> bash: path_to_file/file.ext: Argument list too long

Аналогичные команды не дают результата. Проблема остаётся:

```
`cat data.csv`
```

И так, тоже:

```
$("cat data.csv")
```

Как пофиксить. Подскажите.

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? Зачем вам в команде содержимое csv-файла?

Comment: @VladD я хочу взять названия файлов, которые сложены в `data.csv` и записать их в переменную. В частности, я эту переменную отдам затем скрипту.

Comment: @VladD [здесь](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060) я нашёл некоторое описание проблемы. Но всюду говорится, что размер строки слишком большой. Но, простите, у меня аргумент длиной не более 200 символов. Что это за прикол такой?

Comment: Хм, а зачем так? Вы можете легко исчерпать размер буфера, отведённого для передачи командной строки. Почему бы не передать нужный список как входной поток?

Comment: @VladD Каким образом это можно сделать? А что если таких списков много?

Comment: Например, через cat? `cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv | script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. вам надо сохранить содержимое в переменную, а вы пытаетесь «выполнить» это содержимое. т.е., вместо

   ```
   $(cat файл)
   ```

   вам надо что-нибудь вроде

   ```
   переменная=$(cat файл)
   ```

   или хотя бы

   ```
   echo $(cat файл)
   ```
2. чтобы убрать символы `\r` (шестнадцатиричное `0d`), можно воспользоваться, например, программой *tr*:

   ```
   переменная=$(cat файл | tr -d '\r')
   ```